# Is there a pattern matching type in Typescript?

Tags: javascript, typescript

So for example, I want the following typings:

```
declare module "*.scss" {
    export const col1: string
    export const col2: string
    export const col3: string
    export const col4: string
    export const col5: string
    export const col6: string
}
```

Is there a way I can just do for example,

```
declare module "*.scss" {
    export const col[0-9]: string
}
```

So just look for a pattern and match it?

Comment: You can use [template literal types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-1.html#template-literal-types) to help describe the types you're talking about like [this](https://tsplay.dev/mMyVzm), but I don't know of a way to *export variables* in a programmatic way.

Comment: why not going with TS array? I think thats best use case here.. no?